# Could not find a part of the path 'W:\Icons\image,png'. Class : System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7

I mapped the network drive W:\ directory.Load image file to load the path specified in the subject and give that error.
Asp.net app pool is configured as a local server, local system, network server and all allow phonetic typing combination yielded no
I also tried to set an asp.net app pool such as available network service full path that is mapped to w:\ directory give error:
"Access to the path '\ip address\flder dir\image.png' is denied.
Class: System.UnauthorizedAccessException"
Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the Application Pool users security rights on the directory where the image is.

Comment: on this link is local direcory ,my problem is network sher direcotry

Comment: It is the same prinicpal.  The security rights will be available on the network share directory, you just need to add your Application Pool user to the directory permissions and set the Read permission.

Comment: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

Comment: How to set up access rights: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363156%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: in preview version I don't tuch rights and aplicaion perfect work

Comment: You mean, how to change the user of the Application Pool?

Comment: if app poll user is user how presentation web app??

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't follow you.  Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: I would like to set an app pool, or site to connect to a network drive as published user who is registered at that address, not a default user?